# Is Xcode 13 Beta 3 missing cktool?

Tags: xcode

Has anyone else found that cktool didn't get installed with Xcode 13 beta 3? xcrun reports it's not a tool, and locate doesn't find it.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anybody else is stuck, you need to register the beta as the "working" version of Xcode ... Assuming you've moved the beta package to the Applications folder,

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode-beta.app
```

Cheers!